# Testflight (Apple) In-App Purchases (IAP) Multiple purchase dialogs

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, testflight

I am testing my IAP and followed the process outlined by Medium here (https://medium.com/flutter-community/in-app-purchases-with-flutter-a-comprehensive-step-by-step-tutorial-b96065d79a21).

Everything works fine in Android but on iOS, I get multiple instances of the purchase dialog asking for my password before the process will complete.  I've found a few scattered posts online saying it's related to the 'Sandbox' environment that Testflight uses.

So, is this really 'normal' for Testflight?  Is there a solution or workaround to solve this?  Also - I added a sandbox tester account in App Store Connect but cannot add this email to the internal testing group for the testflight build, how do i do that?

Comment: Yep, it's incredibly annoying and incredibly "normal". What you see on iOS is just not at all identical to what the user will see in real life.

Comment: Yes, same thing here. When you create a new account, 1st purchase on each of your plans will display a double purchase dialog (sandbox only, production is fine). I've created a ticket on this subject, but no resolution yet. Maybe you could create one too, it could help them prioritise: https://feedbackassistant.apple.com/